# What happens in Firebase when I reach simultaneous connection limit (Android)?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

According to Firebase FAQ:

> When your application reaches the concurrent connections limit in the Spark plan, all subsequent connections are rejected until some of
>   the existing connections are terminated. The app will continue to work
>   for users who are connected.

I want to understand (in terms of programming flow) what is going to happen? Will my app crash?

Answer (score 0):

You should expect that any Task objects returned from reads or writes will result in errors, and any onCancelled callbacks on listeners will be called with an error.